# Using CreateML Model in Xcode (ActivityClassifier)

Tags: swift, xcode, createml

I created an activity classifier model using CreateML and imported the model into my XCode project. And am trying to find answers to the following questions.. I created the instance of the model like this:

`let activityClassifier = MyActivityClassifier_4()`

1. How am I supposed to access the constants of the model? For example, the prediction window value that shows here on the metadata of the model. I am having hard time finding an example code to get these values. I tried something along these line `let predictionWindowSize = activityClassifier.model.modelParameters` but could not figure it out.
   [image]

2. Also, the model expects `stateIn` as an input. How can I create an empty MLMultiArray that matches the expected shape?
   `stateIn: MLMultiArray(shape: <#T##[NSNumber]#>, dataType: <#T##MLMultiArrayDataType#>)`
   I assume there is a suggested way to fetch features shape and etc...

I would greatly appreciate if you could also direct me on how to find these answers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the metadata by accessing `modelDescription.metadata`. For author, description, license, and version, you can use the appropriate [`MLModelMetadataKey`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml/mlmodelmetadatakey):

e.g.

```
let model = try! MyActivityClassifier_4(configuration: .init()).model
let author = model.modelDescription.metadata[.author]
```

For the metadata in the "additional metadata" section, you need to use the `.creatorDefinedKey` key to get a nested dictionary. Things like `prediction_windows` are stored *there*.

```
if let dict = model.modelDescription.metadata[.creatorDefinedKey] as? [String: Any],
   let predictionWindow = dict["prediction_window"] {
    print(predictionWindow)
}
```

For the inputs, you can see the shape and type of the array just by going to the "Predictions" tab after opening your model in Xcode.

[image]

In this case, both of the inputs shown above would be a double array with a single dimension, 100 elements in length. You can create it like this.

```
MLMultiArray(shape: [100], dataType: .double)
```

If you want to do this programmatically, you can too. Just give the name of your input to `model.modelDescription.inputDescriptionsByName`, and get the `multiArrayConstraint`.

```
if let constraint = model.modelDescription.inputDescriptionsByName["stateIn"]?.multiArrayConstraint {
    print(constraint.shape)
    print(constraint.dataType)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! How are these two different? `let model = try! MyActivityClassifier_4(configuration: .init()).model` and `let activityClassifier = MyActivityClassifier_4()` then accessing model in activityClassifier?

Comment: @Megool The parameterless `init` for `MLModel` is deprecated. (Did Xcode not generate a warning for this?) You should use the throwing `init(configuration:)` and handle errors correctly (Though for the sake of example here, I didn't do this).

Comment: gotcha, thanks. You seem to be pretty experienced with CoreML. Do you mind taking a look at my other question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77150967/statein-input-for-activityclassifier-in-coreml